# Design pattern for generating diagnostic messages

Tags: design-patterns

in software engineering, there is a frequent need for reporting helpful warnings and error messages back to the user. There are usually two types of messages: the generic ones and the diagnostic ones. For instance, when implementing a compiler, a generic message could be something like: "encountered an error while parsing file at xxxxx:line:column", while a diagnostic message would say something like, "did you forget an ; at xxxxx:line:column?".

I am not actually writing a compiler, but a software that has a similar challenge as a compiler, that is to generate diagnostic warning messages during the runtime, depending on user input. A lot of times I found myself writing code like this;

```
if (only event 1 happens) {
   remember event 1 has happened
   output warning A
}

if (only event 2 happens) {
   remember event 2 has happened
   output warning B
}

if (only event 3 happens) {
   remember event 3 has happened
   output warning C
}

if (during event 1, event 2 happens) {
   output a more specific warning
}

// because the order of events matter
if (during event 2, event 1 happens) {
   output a different specific warning
}

if (event 2 and event 3 happen) {
   output a more specific warning
}

many if's...
```

As you can tell, I ended up checking many combinations of events and the code is not maintainable. Every time a new feature is added, there is a new event that needs to be taken into account, combining with the old events. therefore, the number of `if`'s grows expotentially.

I'd like to know if there is some sort of OOP design pattern I could apply to my code, so that instead of writing `if`'s on a case-by-case basis, I could make use of the virtual inheritance of OOP languages to better maintain this code.

Answer (score 1):

I think if your message generation logic is too branchy, you could use State Machine instead of a design pattern.